# Git fork - rebase multiple branches - preserver shared commits

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have cloned a public repository.  In my local repository I have a branch structure like this where letters represent commits:

```
[public tag: v1] - A - B - C [myBranch1]
                       \
                        \- D [myBranch2]
```

The public repo has moved and released a new tag "v2".  I want to rebase my branches onto the new version so I did:

```
git rebase --onto v2 v1 myBranch1
git rebase --onto v2 v1 myBranch2
```

This seems to work, except it creates distinct copies of commits A and B with the same contents but different hash codes:

```
[public tag: v2] - A' - B' - C' [myBranch1]
                 \
                  \A''- B''- D' [myBranch2]
```

I realize I could do something more complicated like:

```
git rebase --onto v2 v1 myBranch1
git rebase --onto myBranch1 B myBranch2
```

This should give me the result that I want but is quite a bit more complicated, particularly if/when I create more additional branches.  It's far more error prone as I go fishing for commit hashcodes and have to keep track of where each branch diverged from which other branch.

1) Is there a better way to achieve this result?  I guess you *could* suggest alternative workflows, but I'm pretty sure this is the kind of branch/commit structure I'd like to maintain.

2) *Why* do the hash codes of A' and A'' differ?  Aren't they the product of applying the same diff/author/timestamp to the same baseline/contents?  I realize the two are produced as two separate operations, but I would have expected those operations to be deterministic and therefore "collide"(correctly).

Answer (score 3):

1) You could automate the finding of `B` by using `merge-base`:

```
git merge-base myBranch1 myBranch2
```

will give you B

2) Rebase is not really moving the original commits, it is rather copying them, or actually replaying the difference that each commit caused. The rebased commits will always have new hashes.

The hash in the commit is a checksum of not only all the content of the entire tree of files that are version controlled, but also of the hash of the parent commit. So even if you would reproduce the same file tree (unlikely) you would still get a new hash since you have a different parent.

Comment: merge-base will be very useful if I do decide to try to automate this, or to understand someone elses automation.  I understand

Comment: append: your initial point 2 but I think torek hit on the right answer as to why A'' and A' come out with different hashes.

Comment: A" and A' have different hashes since their time stamp for the commit differs I think. Thats the only thing I can think that would be different for the commits.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson the commit hash indirectly takes the entire file tree into account, not just changes made by the commit. So, in this scenario, where rebase is made on a different tag, presumably other files have changed except for the changes introduced by the latest commit. Thus, you will have different hashes for that reason too.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn, The differences in the history and file tree would explain the differences between A and A' or between A and A", but A' and A" have the same history and file tree... all that differs is their committer time stamp. (Their author timestamps should be the same too).

Comment: Turns out since all that differs between A' and A'' is the committer timestamp you can merge A' and A'' back together by running a `git filter-branch` on parts of mybranch1 and mybranch2 that resets the committer timestamp to the author timestamp. But IMO thats an overkill approach.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson It sounded to me like the OP was rebasing the branches on a different commit than the original one (and thus presumably a different tree content). But maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

[Klas Mellbourn beat me to it; my answer just expands his a bit at this point.]

For what it's worth, I've seen a few attempts at "group or en masse rebase" methods that allow this sort of thing.  They all need some way of choosing which branch to rebase first, and then to rebase other "dependent" branches on the now-rebased branch.

The answers to these are thus:

1. No, except that you can automate this.  How *well* you can automate it is another question entirely. :-)  The scripts I've seen were not as clever as they should be.  (An automated system *should* grovel over all the branches, compute the appropriate merge bases for each, and do a minimal set of rebase/cherry-pick operations, recording enough "start state" to allow you to do `--abort` or  `--continue` when hitting points that require manual resolution.  This requires delaying the moves of the various branch labels too.)
2. `A''` has a different commit timestamp, vs `A'` (if it had the exact same commit metadata and the same tree it would indeed wind up being the same actual new commit).  As [Klas Mellbourn noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295020/1256452), once `A''` is different, everything else will be as well.

Comment: So the timestamp that's listed inside the commit (which is the same for both A'' and A') is not what's relevant?  Or maybe it is also relevant, but apparently it also takes into account the system time at the time the commit hash is computed? +1

Comment: I'd have to check with `git cat-file -p` on each of the two different commits, to see precisely which bits are different, but I'll bet that the (same) time stamp you're seeing is the "author" time stamp rather than the (different) "committer" time stamp.

Comment: You are correct.  The committer timestamps differ, thus the hashes.  Thx for the input :)